# Programmatically export .exe file in vb.net with resources

Tags: vb.net, compilation

i know this might be a none straightforward question but i want to make a program that can export a simple vb.net written .exe file i have done some googleing but came out with nothing more than compile and run code but i want to export to exe not only compile and run thank you in advance.
ps: not trying to make an IDE or something.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to create an installer? You don't need to create a program to export to .exe's since Visual Studio does that for you when you compile a project. Check this folder: `{Solution}\{Project}\bin\{Debug|Release}\{Project}.exe`

Comment: what i am doing is trying to make a program that makes installers .